# Oracle light weight directory access protocol

Tags: ldap, access-control

I am using Oracle Lightweight directory manager of version 170717. I am trying to provide restricted access to my ldap by using ip bind keyword. But after some time around 20+ minutes. When I try to log in using the Ip in localhost the ldap is unable to connect. On chekcing the logs the ldap crashes and starts once again. Upon restarting the Oracle service the issue sorts out. I have attached the screen shot of it. Can you help me out

I tried adding the ip using the following syntax.

```
(target ="ldap:///o=nmc")(targetfilter="objectclass=NmcHost")(targetattr ="IpAddress")(version 3.0;acl "NmcHost read-search access";allow (read, search, compare)  (userdn = "ldap:///anyone" **and ip = "172.xx.xx.xx"**);)
(target ="ldap:///o=nmc")(targetfilter !="(|(objectclass=oxepcs)(objectclass=radiusserver) (objectclass=ReverseProxy)(objectclass=NmcDomain))")(targetattr !="userPassword || CmisdPassWord || FtpPassWord || swinstpassword || RasPbxPassword || RasPPPOXOPassword || RasPPPPassword || ConfigPassword || PinNumber || IpAddress || SecretCode || MacAddress || PublicIpAddress|| PhysicalIpAddress || MaintenanceLogin || MaintenancePassword || password || RasPPPRMAPassword || HttpUrgAlmAuthPassword || HttpUrgAlmProxyPassword || authenticationMode || ManagementURL || AdminPassword || cnattribute || fqdn || TUIPassword || SIPPassword || resetpwdcode")(version 3.0;acl "Anonymous read-search access";allow (read, search, compare)  (userdn = "ldap:///anyone" **and ip = "172.xx.xx.xx"**);)
```